# Extract URL from an string retreived by API with backwards slashes

Tags: php, wordpress, api, url

So I am retrieving an URL from an API (from wordpress), however the URL I get has backwards slashes and I am not managing to extract the URL from the string so I can parse it
this is what the received API string looks like:

```
string(93) "{"url":"https:\/\/api.mysite.com\/downloads\/?h=153dcf3eca49a51&d=123332221"}"
```

And I need to get the hash key after the query ?h=

```
153dcf3eca49a51&d=123332221
```

However I am having a pretty hard time, I have tried stripslashes() and Regex but the string is obtained from an array and I am not being able to figure it out.

This is how the URL is obtained:

```
function get_api_data() {


$url = "https://api.mysite.com/?access_token=1234567";


$arguments = array(
    'method' => 'POST',

$response = wp_remote_post( $url, $arguments );

if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
    $error_message = $response->get_error_message();
    return "Something went wrong: $error_message";
} else {
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ) );
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

What would be the best practice for cleaning the entire string and only obtaining the hash key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the functions that are purpose built for each task:

```
$response = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);
parse_str(parse_url(json_decode($response, true)['url'], PHP_URL_QUERY), $result);
echo $result['h'];
```

- Decode the JSON string into a PHP array `json_decode($response, true)` and then access the `url` element `['url']`:

  - `Array ( [url] => https://api.mysite.com/downloads/?h=153dcf3eca49a51&d=123332221 )`
- Parse that URL with `parse_url` to get the query string `PHP_URL_QUERY`:

  - `h=153dcf3eca49a51&d=123332221`
- Parse the query string with `parse_str` into an array `$result` of variables and values and access the `h` element:

  - `Array ( [h] => 153dcf3eca49a51 [d] => 123332221 )`

Comment: I struggled to understand some parts of it as a newbie, but this works very well and is very neat and straightforward to the point! Thank you Abracadaver

Comment: Edit with some more detail.

Answer (score 1):

These are "escapes"... try decoding the (JSON?) string first: https://www.php.net/json_decode

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples, please try following regex.

```
(?<=\?h=)[^"]+
```

Online demo for above regex is: [Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/93LwSp/1/)

***Explanation:*** Looking everything till `"` and making sure if its preceded by `\?h=`(by using positive look behind method), if yes then match the value.

Answer (score 0):

The backward from your string come from your JSON escapes propably. So, you could first you [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php) your data:

```php
function get_api_data() {
  $url = "https://api.mysite.com/?access_token=1234567";
  $arguments = array(
      'method' => 'POST',
  );
  $response = wp_remote_post( $url, $arguments );

  if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
      $error_message = $response->get_error_message();
      return "Something went wrong: $error_message";
  } else {
      echo '<pre>';
      var_dump( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ) );
      echo '</pre>';
      $json = json_decode(wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ));
      echo $json->url;
  }
}
```

Then, to take anything after "?h=", you can use:

```php
substr($json->url, strpos($json->url, "?h=") + 3)
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining it so succinctly! I was not aware of json_decode before so the way you put it is really clarifying, thank you!